# transform an xml into suitable text

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I have an xml, that looks like this

```
<person>
   <name>
      <name-first>foo</name-first>
      <name-last>bar</name-last>
   </name>
   <age>20</age>
   <city>nowhere</city>
 </person>
```

I want to convert this into

```
person:
   {
     name: {
             name-first:'foo', 
             name-last:'bar'  
           }, 
    age:'20',
    city:'nowhere' 
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many programming languages have a XML library so you could easily create a quick program to do this for you. You could also do this with string manipulation if your favorite language doesn't hava a XML library.

Comment: @ingo vals - thanks for response, @oded - i've tried the following <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:value-of select="(/*)"/>
 <xsl:for-each select="*">
 {
  <xsl:value-of select="name(.)" /> : <xsl:value-of select="." />
 }
 </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>, but i dont get what I want. please help.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and simple XSLT solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a simple transformation -- for a start**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pIndents" select="'  '"/>

 <xsl:template match="*[*]">
   <xsl:param name="pcurrentIndents" select="''"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="concat($pcurrentIndents, name(), ':')"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;',$pcurrentIndents, '{')"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:with-param name="pcurrentIndents" select=
         "concat($pcurrentIndents, $pIndents)"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;',$pcurrentIndents,  '}')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
  <xsl:param name="pcurrentIndents" select="''"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($pcurrentIndents, name(), ':')"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<person>
    <name>
        <name-first>foo</name-first>
        <name-last>bar</name-last>
    </name>
    <age>20</age>
    <city>nowhere</city>
</person>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
person:
{  name:
  {
    name-first:foo
    name-last:bar
  }
  age:20
  city:nowhere
}
```

**Explanation**:

1. There are two templates that match elements.
2. The template matching `*[*]` matches elements that have elements as children. It produces the name of the currently matched element using the `name()` function, then the `:` character, then a NL charactr, the current indentation (number of spaces) and finally the `{` character. Then templates are applied to the children-nodes of the currently matched element with the `$pcurrentIndents` parameter passing the current indentation increased with a predifined increment of space characters (as specified in the global parameter `$pIndents` Finally, on a new line and using the current indentation, the closing curly brace is putput.
3. The template that matches `*[not(*)]` (elements that dont have any element as a child) is similar, but simpler. It Outputs the name of the matched element at the current indentation and the `:` character. Applying templates here invokes th XSLT built-in templates for non-element nodes -- in this case the built-in template matching a text node is selected and it simply copies the text node to the output.

Comment: thanks for such a wonderful response. Your code works really well but, I still need few more modifications like - adding commas ',' at the end of the lines. I will be glad if you can share/explain me how this code works, which would be a great learning/understanding XML.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'll try to modify it to suit my requirements.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is an XML to JSON converter.

Try this one: http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example xsl template which should give you some idea of how to convert your xml to the required output:

```
<xsl:template match="person">
person:
   {
     name: {
             name-first:<xsl:value-of select="name/name-first"/>, 
             name-last:<xsl:value-of select="name/name-last"/>  
           }, 
    age:<xsl:value-of select="age"/>,
    city:<xsl:value-of select="city"/> 
  }
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: yep, thats true. But, i wanted a more generic way of doing it, without specifying the node names explicitly. What i mean is, if I add few more nodes to my XML, the XSL should still give the output without any modification. Anyways, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of general-purpose XSLT solutions available for converting XML into JSON output.

For instance:

- http://code.google.com/p/xml2json-xslt/
- http://www.bramstein.com/projects/xsltjson/

I ran your XML through **[xml2json-xslt's](http://code.google.com/p/xml2json-xslt/)** `xml2json.xslt` and generated the following JSON output:

```
{
  "person":
     {
       "name":
         {
           "name-first":"foo",
           "name-last":"bar"
         },
         "age":20,
         "city":"nowhere"
      }
 }
```